# How to find records missing associated records in has_many through association with Active Record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let'say, we have "Topic - Relationship - Category".

That is, Topic has_many categories through relationship.

I think its very easy to get the topics that with a category

```
  #Relationship  Model
  Topic_id: integer
  Category_id: integer

  @topics=Topic.joins(:relationships)
```

But, not every topic has a category. So how do we retrieve the topic which has no category?
Is there a **minus** query?

Perhaps it looks like `@topics=Topic.where('id NOT IN (?)', Relationship.all)`
I find it in [activerecord equivalent to SQL 'minus'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428852/activerecord-equivalent-to-sql-minus) but not sure about this solution.

Comment: Can you not get the list by something like `Topic.where(:categories.nil?)`

Comment: AR returns an empty array when nothing is found in a relationship not nil.

Comment: @tester123, cheers for the clarification, I've been using Datamapper for a while.

Comment: the rails solution is to use includes: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48877930/1536309

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Would be better as a relation, really. Think this would work:

```
@topics = Topic.joins('left join relationships on relationships.topic_id = topics.id').where('relationships.category_id is null')
```

Or this:

```
@topics = Topic
    .joins('left join relationships on relationships.topic_id = topics.id join categories on categories.id = relationships.category_id')
    .group('topics.id').having('count(categories.id) = 0')
```

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for the simplest answer, which i think is to use `includes`.

`topics = Topic.includes(:relationships).where(relationships: {id: nil})`

Another way, which is more correct and gets you thinking SQL is `LEFT OUTER JOINS`.

```
Topic.joins("LEFT OUTER JOINS relationships ON relationships.topic_id = topics.id")
     .where(relationships: {id: nil})
```

Answer (score 1):

For newer Rails (6.1 and above)
we can do something like

> Topic.where.missing(:categories)

[Find records missing an association with `where.missing`](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/34727)