# Using Ruby with active record How do I access joined columns?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, activerecord

I am trying to join my Person table to my Address table with the ultimate goal of purging addresses with a pointer to a non-existent person.

Here is my Address model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :person, foreign_key: "fk_personID"
end
```

Here is the code I'm running:

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'development'
require_relative './config/environment'
    
@address = Address.joins(:person)
.select("addresses.id,street1,people.first_name,people.last_name").limit 5
puts @address.to_sql
puts @address.inspect

@address.each do |adr|
    puts "Address = " + adr.inspect
end
```

Here is the SQL first (from puts @address.to_sql), followed by the output.

```
SELECT addresses.id,street1,people.first_name,people.last_name FROM "addresses" INNER JOIN "people" ON "people"."id" = "addresses"."fk_personID" LIMIT 5
#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Address id: 2, street1: "CMR 431, Box 2837">, #<Address id: 3, street1: "1665 Ashland Bluff Way">, #<Address id: 4, street1: "56 Back St. Port Herman">, #<Address id: 6, street1: "1757 Reising Rd">, #<Address id: 7, street1: "81 Old Mill Road">]>

Address = #<Address id: 2, street1: "CMR 431, Box 2837">
Address = #<Address id: 3, street1: "1665 Ashland Bluff Way">
Address = #<Address id: 4, street1: "56 Back St. Port Herman">
Address = #<Address id: 6, street1: "1757 Reising Rd">
Address = #<Address id: 7, street1: "81 Old Mill Road">
```

And here is what I get when I paste the generated SQL into SQLite:

```
2|CMR 431, Box 2837|Mark|Dorn
3|1665 Ashland Bluff Way|Mark|Wild
4|56 Back St. Port Herman|Alfonse|Prince
6|1757 Reising Rd|Andrew|Rigotta
7|81 Old Mill Road|Angie|Ganno
```

So, the data is definitely in the table and available via sql, but when it is absorbed by active_record, the joined columns disappear.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get access to person.first_name from the program.  I used the first_name column in the example just because it's easy to identify in the output.

I've tried using 'includes' instead of 'joins' and everything I can think of over the last 2 days and I'm stumped.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587540/how-to-find-records-missing-associated-records-in-has-many-through-association-w

Answer (score 0):

first let me know your rails and ruby versions. I also had the same problem with old rails.
And how I solve them:

```
sql = 'SELECT address.id, street1, people.first_name, people.last_name FROM address INNER JOIN people ON address.people_id = people.id LIMIT 5'
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql).to_a
=> array
```

Comment: Rails 6.1.7.3

ruby 3.2.0 (2022-12-25 revision a528908271) [i386-mingw32]

Your suggested solution worked for me.